# How to make print at right side of screen?

Tags: python-3.x

is there any way for my program to print like such? I want the `Building    Remaining` to be on the right side of the screen, and find any good way to put it there. The only criteria is for `Building    Remaining` to be the same row as `A    B    C    D`:

```
     A     B     C     D                                            Building     Remaining
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+                                         --------     ---------
1 |     |     |     |     |                                         BCH          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+                                         FAC          8
2 |     |     |     |     |                                         HSE          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+                                         SHP          8
3 |     |     |     |     |                                         HWY          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

This is how my current print looks like, with the `Building   Remaining` at the bottom of the grid:

```
     A     B     C     D 
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
2 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
3 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
4 |     |     |     |     |
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
Building     Remaining
--------     ---------
BCH          8
FAC          8
HSE          8
SHP          8
HWY          8
```

Below is how my program currently looks:

```
building_list = [['BCH', 8], ['FAC', 8], ['HSE', 8], ['SHP', 8], ['HWY', 8]]

basket = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]


columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


cols_string = ""
        
for n in range(4):
    cols_string += "    {:2}".format(columns[n])

#printing table
print("",cols_string, end="")
        
for idx, i in enumerate(basket):

    print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')
    print(idx + 1, end=" ")
    for j in i:
        
        print('|{:^5}'.format(j), end = '')

    print('|', end = '')

print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')

print('Building \t Remaining')
print('-------- \t ---------')
for x in building_list:
    print('{} \t\t {}'.format(x[0], x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this appears to be a school-related problem, I think it's crucial to point out that a key component in programming is **clarity**. If the logic behind a program is unclear, then that code base has to be refactored or scrapped completely which is both time-consuming and costly. Anyone who aspires to be a software developer needs to learn how to write clean code first.

```
def build_table1():
    '''Builds a 4 x 4 alphanumeric grid'''
    table1 = []

    table1_header_text = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', '']
    table1_header = ' {:>6}{:>6}{:>6}{:>6}{:>30}'.format(*table1_header_text)
    table1.append(table1_header)

    h_line = '+-----' * 4 + '+'
    v_line = '|'
    for i in range(1,6):
        h_row = ' {:<2}{}{:>27}'.format(i, h_line, '')
        v_row = '{:>4}{:>6}{:>6}{:>6}{:>6}{:>27}'.format(v_line, v_line, v_line, v_line, v_line, '')
        if i != 5:
            table1.append(h_row)
            table1.append(v_row)
        else:
            table1.append(h_row)
    return table1

def build_table2():
    '''Builds a list of remaining building'''
    table2 = []

    table2_header_text = ['Building', 'Remaining']
    table2_header = ' {}{:>17}'.format(*table2_header_text)
    table2.append(table2_header)

    h_row = ' -------- \t ---------'
    table2.append(h_row)

    list_data = [['BCH', 8], ['FAC', 8], ['HSE', 8], ['SHP', 8], ['HWY', 8]]
    for entry in list_data:
        row = ' {}{:>14}'.format(*entry)
        table2.append(row)
    return table2

def main():
    table1, table2 = build_table1(), build_table2()
    for _ in range(len(table1) - len(table2)):
        table2.append('')
    for j, k in zip(table1, table2):
        print('{} {}'.format(j, k))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For the sake of completeness, it should be noted that, ideally, the code above should be generalised for other data inputs than the one provided by OP but since this is a school assignment, I'll leave it up to OP to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to install Pandas and numpy library, just fill the value in a Spreadsheet[image: spreadsheet_01] and put file path in your code as follows and see if you like the output

```
w=pd.read_excel('spreadsheet_01.xlsx')
w.fillna(' ',inplace=True)
print(w)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your suggestion, but my school only allows us to use in built programs, that's why I am struggling with this

Comment: I see, can you check if csv module is already installed? You can pull off similar thing with csv module as well

Comment: hi, yes. CSV is installed

Answer (score 0):

I think new logic from scratch will be too much work so

```
output_left=''
output_right=''
building_list = [['BCH', 8], ['FAC', 8], ['HSE', 8], ['SHP', 8], ['HWY', 8]]

basket = [ [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],\
            [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] ]


columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]


cols_string = ""
        
for n in range(4):
    cols_string += "    {:2}".format(columns[n])

#printing table
#print("",cols_string, end="")
output_left+=' '+cols_string
        
for idx, i in enumerate(basket):

    #print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')
    output_left+='\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+'+'\n'
    #print(idx + 1, end=" ")
    output_left+=str(idx+1)+" "
    for j in i:
        
        #print('|{:^5}'.format(j), end = '')
        output_left+='|{:^5}'.format(j)

    #print('|', end = '')
    output_left+='|'

#print('\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+')
output_left+='\n  ' + '+-----' * 4 + '+'



#print('Building \t Remaining')
output_right+='Building \t Remaining'+'\n'
#print('-------- \t ---------')
output_right+='-------- \t ---------'+'\n'
for x in building_list:
    #print('{} \t\t {}'.format(x[0], x[1]))
    output_right+='{} \t\t {}'.format(x[0], x[1])+'\n'
    
print(output_left)
print(output_right)
right_lines=list(output_right.split('\n'))
left_lines=list(output_left.split('\n'))
right_lines.append(' ')
right_lines.append(' ')
for i in range(10):
    print(left_lines[i]+'\t\t'+right_lines[i])
```

Output:

```
     A     B     C     D        Building     Remaining
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+     --------     ---------
1 |     |     |     |     |     BCH          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+     FAC          8
2 |     |     |     |     |     HSE          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+     SHP          8
3 |     |     |     |     |     HWY          8
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+     
4 |     |     |     |     |      
  +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi harash. Thank you so much for your help, I manage to get the code working now. Appriciate it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to control where your text appears is to use the following notation.

The `>40` will control the amount of space to the left of the text 'name', in this case 40 spaces.

Similarly, `<40` will insert 40 spaces to the right of 'name'

```py
name = 'Your text to display'
for a in range( 10 ):
    print( f"{name:>40}" )
```

In order to define different space lengths between text the following function can be used.

```py
def make( var, name, n ):
    """make( (name of variable name), (text to display), (required extra space)"""
    ln = len( name ) + n
    return f'{var} = f"' + "{"+( f"'{name}'" +":>{}".format( ln ) ) + '}"'

# name of variable name, text to display, required extra space
exec( make( "a", name, 30 ) )
exec( make( "b", name, 10 ) )
exec( make( "c", name, 10 ) )

print( a, b, c )
```